# golang: Execute shell commands on remote server

Tags: ssh, go, remote-access

I have 50 something Linux machines (RHEL). I want to run some commands on these machines from a go script running on a central machine. I have setup password-less ssh authentication to all of them from the central machine to all the remote machines. Though I'm open to non-ssh solutions too, though something secure is preferred.

The commands being run would change over time. I would also want to process the output and return codes of commands being run on the remote machines in my script running on central machine.

I only found this [ssh package](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh#example-Dial), which supports only password authentication method, which is not good enough.

Any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use public keys with the `go.crypto/ssh` package using [`PublicKeys`](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh#PublicKeys).

There's a detailed example in the [repo](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/ssh/client_auth_test.go?repo=crypto#114) around line 114.

Another example using ssh agent @ https://github.com/davecheney/socksie/blob/master/main.go.

Comment: So it's a documentation bug then. :) `Currently only
// the "password" authentication method is supported`

Answer (score 4):

You just can use this package https://github.com/hypersleep/easyssh

For example you can call `ps ax` remotely:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/hypersleep/easyssh"    
)

func main() {
    ssh := &easyssh.MakeConfig {
        User: "core",
        Server: "core",
        Key: "/.ssh/id_rsa",
        Port: "22",
    }

    response, err := ssh.Run("ps ax")
    if err != nil {
        panic("Can't run remote command: " + err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println(response)
    }
}
```